# redirect to controller from script file with param in Magento2

Tags: magento2, controllers, redirect

I have created a script file in root folder of the magento as like below

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
use \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '../../app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager(); 
$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$resource = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
$connection = $resource->getConnection();
$response = $_REQUEST;
/* echo '<pre>';
print_r($response);die;*/

$unique_code= $response['unique_code'];
$this->_redirect("custom/services/custompage", ['unique_code' => 
$unique_code]);
```

In above code I am trying to redirect to my custom controller, with parameter,

but the above code is not working. Can anyone tell me how can we redirect to controller with parameter.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this below script in your root file :

```
<?php
error_reporting(1);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
use \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');
$urlInterface = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\UrlInterface');
$params = ['name' => 'Rohan'];
$url = $urlInterface->getUrl('custom/index/index', $params);
header('Location:' . $url);die();
```

Then, you can get params value in your controller :

```
print_r($this->getRequest()->getParams());
```

Hope, It will helpful for you !!